# Explain better this new inventory for Word Sense Disambiguation

Tags: natural-language-processing

My question is about CSI (Coarse Sense Inventory), described in the paper [CSI A Coarse Sense Inventory for 85% Word Sense Disambiguation](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Tommaso_Pasini/publication/337473634_CSI_A_Coarse_Sense_Inventory_for_85_Word_Sense_Disambiguation/links/5dd9dcc9a6fdccdb44600369/CSI-A-Coarse-Sense-Inventory-for-85-Word-Sense-Disambiguation.pdf) (C Lacerra, M Bevilacqua, T Pasini, R Navigli).

Before the question, let me quickly describe the new CSI using phrases taken from the above paper.

CSI is a "a resource that avoids sense distinctions that are
too **ﬁne-grained** for WSD, while maintaining a granularity that is still meaningful for the task".

CSI is "obtained by linking WordNet concepts to a new set of 45 **labels**".

The comparison between WordNet and CSI is given in table 7:

[image]

Question: What is a **semantically-empty** prediction? (The paper doesn't explain well what is a semantically-empty label)

Comment: Would you be willing to [edit] to add a full reference for the paper (title, authors, where published) so that others with a similar question can find this via search?

Answer (score 1):

The paper says:

> "we also added the semantically-empty label named GENERAL to our inventory to cover the 135 categories that could not be included in any cluster."

I suggest you read that as though it had said

> we also added the label named GENERAL to our inventory to cover the 135 categories that could not be included in any cluster.  This label is not associated with one specific semantic meaning; it is a catch-all for the categories that could not be mapped to any of the other labels.

Comment: I have read the above phrases but I still not able to understand what the author says with "semantically-empty label"

Comment: @R.S., that's why I provided the re-wording -- it is an attempt to explain what I suspect they were trying to say.  Don't get too focused on that two-word phrase; it's not some standard term that has meaning outside of the context of that sentence.